# label and input tag width controlled by css

Tags: html, css

i had a look at some examples here and followed one, but it is not wokting. what am i missing please?

```
  fieldset {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:90%
 }
 label {
   padding-left:26px;
   width:250px; 
   display:block; float:left; clear:left;
 }

 input { 
  width:200px;
  display:block; float:left;
 }

 .formFieldDiv { float:left; width:500px }


 <td style="width:70%" align="left" valign="top">   
 <form id="divorce" name="divorce" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
     <fieldset>
        <div id="spouse1" class="formFieldDiv" >
          <label for="spouse1">Full Names + Surname Spouse 1*</label>
          <input type="text" name="spouse1" id="spouse1" maxlength="50" size="30" />                           
        </div>
        <div id="spouse2" class="formFieldDiv">
          <label for="spouse2">Full Names</label>                       
            <input  type="text" name="spouse2" id="spouse2" maxlength="50" size="30"/> 
        </div>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
 </td>
```

what am i missing? I want to get the input's all in line

[image: on the actual page]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/charles_cat/omwth1cy/2/

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to your label

Comment: aaah ok i see let me try in fiddle quick Thanks!

Comment: it works in fiddle but not on my webpage, ill post screenshot

Comment: You can also add `display:block; float:left; clear:left;` to your label and `display:block; float:left;` to your input. That does the same.

Comment: its crazy it works in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/charles_cat/omwth1cy/18/ but not on my page?

Comment: Is your page online? It might be I (or someone else) can help you, if we can see the page.

Comment: yes it is: http://www.familylawclinic.org.za/selfhelp_divorce.html the code is not great, original main page was made in dreamweaver by someone and i have to make my page look exactly the same using html

Comment: The CSS is being commented out in the ´<head>´ - that's why it doesn't work :-)

Comment: .. and you haven't closed the .style31 with a }

Answer (score 2):

```
 formFieldDiv is a class so use . before it in css ie- 
.formFieldDiv { float:left; width:500px } instead of
formFieldDiv { float:left; width:500px }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="spouse1" class="formFieldDiv" >
       <label for="spouse1">address</label>                
       <input type="text" name="spouse1" id="address" maxlength="50" size="30" />                          
     </div>>
```

change `</div>>` to `</div>`

And i need to look your send_form_email.php file

Comment: why would this be relevant? i just want my inputs to be all in line wrt to html